# How can I determine which network my docker compose stack is connected to?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm writing a test runner container for my app and in order to do some debugging and learning: my plan is to have my network-enabled docker compose stack running, while I work in a container that I start and stop manually, and manually adjust the parameters.

I need the container that I am starting to connect to the network of the compose stack.

How do I determine which network my compose stack is using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to run the `docker inspect` command on any of the running containers:

```
docker inspect mycontainer
```

and it returns a lot of information where you can find the network under:

```
NetworkSettings -> Networks -> bridge -> NetworkID
```